# xamarin project suavecontrols referenced in xamarin can be modified in c# but not in xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package

I use a materialentry from the project suavecontrols which link is this https://github.com/SuavePirate/SuaveControls.MaterialFormControls

The problem is the next, if I use the control in C# there is no problem and works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SuaveControls.MaterialEntry;

namespace add_suave_control
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var suavecito = new SuaveControls.MaterialEntry.MaterialEntry
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
            Placeholder = "Escribe",
        };


        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Spacing = 10,
            Children = { suavecito },
        };

        //si agrego controles por c# no hay problema, pero si lo hago por xaml entonces sí
        
    }
}
}
```

But if I try the same in xaml with this code it doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:add_suave_control"
         x:Class="add_suave_control.MainPage"
         xmlns:suave="clr-namespace:SuaveControls.MaterialEntry;assembly=SuaveControls.MaterialEntry">

<suave:MaterialEntry BackgroundColor="Green" Placeholder="PorMientras">

</suave:MaterialEntry>

</ContentPage>
```

For use MaterialEntry I add a reference in Android and pcl to SuaveControls.MaterialEntry.dll and SuaveControls.MaterialEntry.Android.dll

Comment: in their samples they use xmlns:suave="clr-namespace:SuaveControls.MaterialForms;assembly=SuaveControls.MaterialForms"

Comment: thanks, I will check it